# How long decision in process normally takes?

Tags: publications

I have submitted a manuscript to a journal on September after few days the status changed to under review and after 5 months the it changed to all required reviews are completed and immediately to decision in process. It has been 3 weeks that the paper status stuck at decision in process. How long this stage normally takes ?  is it too early to ask the editor (?) about the status of my paper?

Answer (score 4):

No, it is not too early. "Decision in progress" means all the reviews have already been received and what's left is for the editor to make a decision. 3 weeks is pretty long for this. I would write to the journal asking for a status update.

Comment: @Student it means the editor is making a decision and you can expect to receive it within a few days.

Comment: @Student don't think it says anything. 5 days is not overly long when the editors are busy academics. Also, relax - regardless of what happens, there's nothing you can do now.

Comment: @Student the next status is usually 'revise', 'accept' or 'reject' as per the decision. Yes the decision should be written in the website. If it shows 'decision in process', no decision has been made yet.

Comment: @Student "Decision in Progress" might take 2 weeks maybe? If it takes longer than that you can email the journal to ask. "Under editor evaluation" means the editor - not the reviewers - is the one with something to do. In your case I'd guess that all the reviewers were submitted and the handling editor had to make a recommendation to the editor-in-chief.

Comment: @Student that's the decision then: "minor revision". Congrats! You can ask your supervisor for the reviews and comments if you're interested.

Comment: @Student https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/109460/can-i-correct-a-mistake-that-the-reviewers-didnt-spot-in-a-paper-that-has-not-b

Comment: @Student there's no way to tell. If the revisions are minor the editor might make a decision without inviting reviewers, in which case it could be quite short; however if the editor chooses to invite reviewers then it could be months.

Comment: @Student is the mistake major? If it's minor (e.g. a misspelled word) it won't cause any problems. If it's major, then you should mention it to the editor in the resubmission, and he or she might might need to invite reviewers. It won't cause a rejection, but it might take time.

Comment: @Student sounds to me like it's pretty minor and the editor wouldn't need to get it reviewed again. I don't have anything more to say though. Either way the only thing to do is wait. You could get an accept decision tomorrow, or it could be two months from now.

Comment: @Student you mean you didn't write you were making this change in your response to reviewers? If so, it's possible the editor feels you're being deceptive which could lead to rejection. Still, since the reviewer was very positive, I think acceptance is much more likely.

Comment: @Student yup, it means the editor hasn't seen your paper yet. The editor's been invited, but hasn't accepted the invitation. It shouldn't be long before the status changes.

Comment: @Student it means the editor chose to invite reviewers to evaluate your revision, which could mean you'll need another 1+ month before you get a decision.

Comment: @Student no idea. Wait for the editor's response. Seriously, stop worrying, it's not like you can do anything anyway.

Comment: Dear professor Allure. Today the status is ''Required Reviews Completed''. The status under review takes 20 days. The next status will be decision in process? Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @Student yes the next status is decision in process.

Comment: Dear Professor Allure. My paper has been accepted for publication. Now I submited another paper to springer journal and the status is '' reviewers assigned''. Is this means that it is ''under review"? Thank you very much.

Comment: @Student congrats. Yes, that status is about the same as "under review".

Comment: Dear Professor, I have submitted a new paper to elsivier journal. From 6 jul to 30 jul, the status is ''with editor''.  1 Aug 2018 the statut is ''under review''. However today  3 Aug 2018, the stauts ''is decision in process''. It is possible to get acceptance only after two days with reviewers? Notice that my paper is very short.

Comment: @Student It's possible, although rejection is more likely.

Comment: Dear Professor, I hope you are fine. Please I have a question. I submitted a paper to a springer math journal since 4/7/2018. From 24/2/2019 the status of the paper is ''reviewers completed'' however I don't receive the decision. Do you advise me to contact the editor? Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @Student as always, if you're concerned, ask the editor, otherwise be patient. In your case it's only been 3 weeks which is apparently not that long in math (I'm not a mathematician and don't know). You could ask a more senior colleague whether it's out of the ordinary. If it is, then yeah, contact the editor.