# Can I correct a mistake that the reviewers didn't spot in a paper that has not been accepted yet?

Tags: publications, peer-review

Recently my paper was accepted pending major revisions (i.e., not yet accepted), and while following the reviewers' comments and revising my paper, I realized that both reviewers missed a mistake that I made in a function block diagram. What should I do?

1. Correct it and let them know in the joined point-by-point response?
2. Wait until they tell me about it?
3. Ask them to double check that diagram?

I'm afraid it may send the wrong message and I'd look disrespectful by showing them that they missed the mistake.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding a citation after paper is accepted](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/103094/adding-a-citation-after-paper-is-accepted); and a [related thread](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/103109/68958).

Comment: You could email them asking if that block diagram is okay .

Comment: @theenigma017 it was an anonymous review ! so the only way i can get in touch with them is by writing it in the point-by-point response.

Comment: Try asking your prof.

Comment: Just change it and add a note that you noticed and fixed a mistake in diagram 133.21.

Comment: It is a major revision. It will be **reviewed again**, supposedly. Fix it, consider mentioning the fix somewhere, but you don't even have to. The reviewers should review the major revision in its entirety, not just the changes.

Comment: Nitpick: I'm sure your paper was accepted *pending* major revisions. It's not accepted yet.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse As a reviewer, I wouldn't be too happy about an author who made amendments to the original manuscript but failed to mention them in the response. The author should definitely mention the changes made, as an addendum to the point-by-point response to the reviewer's criticisms. A lot of the time, the repeat review goes back to the same reviewer who recommended a major revision, it's only proper to mention all changes made, both in response to, and independent of, the reviewers' criticisms.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix a mistake in an accepted paper?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/83548/how-to-fix-a-mistake-in-an-accepted-paper)

Comment: Possible duplicate [Does correcting the data analysis when replying to a Major Revision make a bad impression on the editors and reviewers?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/107727/546)

Comment: Also, you first say the paper _was accepted_ in the beginning of the question, then you say _THE PAPER HAS NOT BEEN ACCEPTED_ at the end of the question, please clarify which case it is.

Answer (score 191, accepted):

YES.  The responsibility for correctness of the paper is **yours** not the reviewers’.  The reviewers may help you find errors, but that is secondary to their main function: recommending to the editor whether to publish.

Answer (score 127):

Which makes you look worse? Mentioning to the referees that they missed something or publishing a paper with a mistake in it?

**Fix the error and include it in the list of changes you've made.**

Don't mention that the referees missed it, of course. Just do something like "Response to referee 1: ... Response to referee n: ... Other changes: Figure 4 incorrectly showed blah; fixed.."

Answer (score 30):

The text is yours, you can do whatever you want with it (within reason, if you want it to still get accepted, that is).

The reviewers' opinions are just that, opinions. You do not necessarily have to do what they said, although you should justify in the letter why you didn't and how you disagree with them.

And yes, if feasible, you should correct any and all errors that you spot in the process.

Comment: Thanks you very much, and It's not about reviewers as much as it is about misleading readers who may read the paper in case it got accepted. Thank you again

Comment: @rahul People usually have better things to do than worry with that. I'd just ignore it as childish. Because it is, pointing out that the reviewers missed something is pointless, mostly because hey, you wrote it, you missed it first :)

Comment: @KADEMMohammed Readers wouldn't see the difference unless you published a preprint, and if you did, you should probably update the preprint to correct the mistake as well.

Answer (score 19):

If you plan on having other researchers cite your paper (which you hopefully do), then you can count on your mistake being found by others - either directly, by reading your paper and finding the mistake, or by calling out someone who used your paper, inherited your mistake, and will make sure to pass the bad rep on to you. This is the last thing you want.

Correct it. Even if it were disrespectful to the reviewers (it isn't), *not* correcting it can potentially affect you a lot more.

Answer (score 10):

This is a no-brainer... it is your responsibility that the paper is correct, and it will be your reputation that is tarnished when people notice the mistake. Correct it and tell them in the response that you noticed that mistake, but it has been corrected. Nothing wrong with that at all.

Answer (score -4):

I had made such a correction just three days ago for a paper that I had published almost two years ago. A couple of subscripts were missing from my equations in my published paper. I wrote to the editor and politely asked him to correct it. And within a week it was implemented. yay!

The online version has an editor note like: 
(Received 13 May 2016; published 23 September 2016; corrected 3 May 2018)

Comment: This is interesting but doesn't seem relevant to the question, which is about corrections to manuscripts that are still in peer review, not manuscripts that have already been published.